# Как объединить элементы в списке в одно слово

Tags: python

Вот есть список с двумя элементами `my_list =['е', 'ж']`
Как сделать, чтобы в списке получился один элемент `['еж']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list=['е', 'ж'] 
my_list=[''.join(my_list)]
my_list

Out[8]: ['еж']
```